# Unable to click on hyperlink in powershell

Tags: javascript, powershell

I am unable to click on a link using powershell.

```
<a class="abc" href="https://www.tutorialspoint.com/videotutorials/index.php"><i class="fa fa-video tp-banner-icons"></i> 
<span>Videos</span></a>
```

In Powershell:

```
$ie = New-Object -ComObject 'internetExplorer.Application'
$ie.Navigate("https://www.tutorialspoint.com/index.htm")
$search = $ie.Document.getElementsByTagName("a") | where-object {$_.className -eq "abc"}
$search.click()
```

The output I am getting is below:

> ```
> System.__ComObject
> ```

And nothing is clicked on UI of Internet explorer

Comment: What is `$ie`, is that `Invoke-WebRequest`? Please format your code properly.

Comment: $ie = New-Object -ComObject 'internetExplorer.Application'

Comment: Neko Musume, the OP never usees IVR in the posted code and no real reason for him to use that for what the OP is trying to do. The OP is just instantiating InternetExplorer and trying to interact with the site interactively. Mohit, you cannot interact with a non-visible UI. You can only click on a single object, not collections. This [System.__ComObject] is the IE instance, not the element you are after, because the element is never returned. You cannot click on an element that does not present that method. Just typing click does not make it so. What are you really after?

Answer (score 1):

A follow-up to my comment.

It is best to scrape the site to see what is and is not available to you before you travel the interactive route.

You have to scrape the site first to see what is and is nto available using Invoke_webRequest as Neko Musume is alluding to.

```
# Define the target to scrape
$TP = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri 'https://www.tutorialspoint.com/videotutorials' -SessionVariable tp

# Review visible elements. I'm using OGV, but you can clip and paste to notepad
$TP.AllElements  | Out-GridView
$TP.Forms        | Out-GridView
$TP.Forms.Fields | Out-GridView
$TP.Links.href   | Out-GridView
```

Once you know the elements, you then can use your browser to interactively navigate and interact with the target, as long as it is visible.

```
#Define you web target
$RequestURI = "https://www.tutorialspoint.com/videotutorials"

# Create your browser session
$IE         = New-Object -ComObject "InternetExplorer.Application"

# This must be set to true, execute methods on the site.
$IE.Visible = $true 
$IE.Silent  = $true
$IE.Navigate($RequestURI)

# Wait for IE to load
While ($IE.Busy) 
{ Start-Sleep -Seconds 1 }
```

Here is an example from a sample I've given to others. Note this is older code, and the site may have changed things, so, if you try and test with it there it may or may not work anymore. Yet, the concept is the same.

```
$password   = '1234'
$loginUrl   = 'https://pwpush.com'

$ie         = New-Object -com internetexplorer.application
$ie.visible = $true
$ie.navigate($loginUrl)

while ($ie.Busy -eq $true) 
{ Start-Sleep -Seconds 1 }

($ie.document.getElementById('password_payload') | 
select -first 1).value = $password
Start-Sleep -Seconds 1 

$ie.Document.getElementsByName('commit').Item().Click();
Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
```

So, try stepping through the site, something like the below to target what you are after. Again, just ideas for you to try.

```
### Navigating web sites interactively

# Target URL
$url = 'https://www.tutorialspoint.com/videotutorials'


# Get form elements
$FormElements = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -SessionVariable fe

# List all form objects 
$FormElements.Forms       | Clip
$FormElements.InputFields | Clip
$FormElements.ParsedHtml  | Clip
$FormElements.Content     | Clip
$FormElements.Scripts     | Clip
$FormElements.AllElements | Clip

# Get all page source elements page Text
$FormElements.AllElements | 
Select-Object -Expand OuterText 

$FormElements.AllElements | 
Select-Object -Expand InnerText

# Get all tagname elements
$FormElements.AllElements | 
Where{$PSItem.TagName -eq 'a'}

$FormElements.AllElements | 
Where{$PSItem.TagName -eq 'input'}

$FormElements.AllElements | 
Where{$PSItem.TagName -eq 'Button'}

$FormElements.AllElements | 
Where{$PSItem.TagName -eq 'Button'} | 
Select-Object outerHTML

$FormElements.AllElements | 
Where{$PSItem.TagName -eq 'Button'} | 
Select-Object -Expand OuterText

$FormElements.AllElements | 
Where{$PSItem.TagName -eq 'Button'} | 
Select-Object -Expand InnerText


# Get only the submit button that matches the criteria
($FormElements.AllElements | 
Where{$PSItem.TagName -eq 'Button'} | 
Select-Object -Property outerHTML) -Match 'SIGN IN'

$FormElements.AllElements | 
Where{$PSItem.TagName -eq 'Button'} | 
Select-Object -Property * | 
Where innerText -eq 'SIGN IN'



# Use Internet Explorer interactively
$url        = 'https://www.tutorialspoint.com/videotutorials'

$ie         = New-Object -com internetexplorer.application
$ie.Visible = $true
$ie.Navigate($url)

while ($ie.Busy -eq $true) 
{ Start-Sleep -Seconds 1 }

$ie.Document.anchors

# or 

$ie.Document.links
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like `$search` may have more than one result and be an array.
`.Click()` will not work on an array of objects.

You may also want to set IE to Visible for the troubleshooting using:
`$ie.Visible = $true`

It may also be best to not use `className` as the same class name could be reused in the same page. This may be the cause for multiple `$search` results as I suspect. It may be better to match on the `href` and to also use `Select-Object -First 1` to limit your results.